# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'icon' (at chunk-X3RU3DRP.js?v=bbf597e4:2712:254)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

While debugging my TypeScript/React project by running the `pnpm run dev` command, I received this error in the DevTool Console after accessing the Webpage:

```
Navigated to http://dev-zj.example.top/
client.ts:18 [vite] connecting...
client.ts:133 [vite] connected.
chunk-X3RU3DRP.js?v=bbf597e4:2712 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'icon' (at chunk-X3RU3DRP.js?v=bbf597e4:2712:254)
```

This is the dev command in the `package.json`:

```
"dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && export PORT=3001 && vite",
```

What should I do to fix this issue? This icon seems like the antd component used.